# Data is not showing(not uploading) in firebase database in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code and I am uploading a student name and batch name to firebase database. This method is excecuted after user created the account successfully. 
User is created in Authentication but data is not uploaded to database and the only error in logcat is:

> E/SpellCheckerSession: ignoring processOrEnqueueTask due to unexpected mState=TASK_CLOSE scp.mWhat=TASK_CLOSE

```
private void uploadUserDetails(){
        String name = studentName.getText().toString();
        String batch = "BCA";
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        Student student = new Student(name,batch);
        ref.child("Student Details").setValue(student);
    }

public class Student {
    public String name;
    public String batch;

    Student(){
        this.name= "Hello";
        this.batch="Unspecified";
    }
    Student(String name,String batch){
        this.name=name;
        this.batch=batch;
    }
}
```

Comment: Posted student class also

Comment: Are you sure that error has something to do with Realtime Database?  It doesn't looks familiar to me.

Comment: I dont know , data is not updating on Firebase database , thats the only error that I'm getting in my logcat

Comment: Can you include the entire logcat?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet uses a map for storing the student name and his batch, in this map key is string and value is of object type. and putting a value of key "l".

```
    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
    updates.put("l", Arrays.asList(student.batch,student.name));
    ref.child("Student Details").setValue(updates);
```

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned you should use the [edit] link below your contribution to add it directly TO the Answer. Comments are subject to deletion from the site as they should only be used for clarification. I've done it for you, this time :-)